# how to make live search in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

For example, I have **28k** zip data in my DB and each zip has 5 digit range. So if I write first the digit then ajax request gets the data from the database related to this search.

like I write **459** in search and ajax request get the data **45934,45932,45926,45945,45978,4593479,4593480** etc.

So now I want to handle it in the controller and send the data to ajax response for view please share any best way or best **Laravel Query** for implementation?

Comment: "_each zip has 5 digit range_" ... How does 4593480 fit in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guide you with best approaches

1. Create a Model for the Zip Table say it's named as "Zip"
2. Create a Controller to in order to retrieve the ajax requests
3. Create a method to respond to the ajax call lets name it something like "getZip"
4. Create Route to the method above
5. Now in the Controller method above, you may do something like (assuming you keep the value of zip in a column named as "name")

   return response()->json(Zip::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('keyword') . '%')->get());
6. Don't forget to import the Model and type-hint the request as $request in the method
7. Now you may send ajax request to the above endpoint with keyword and you will get the result matched to your keyword

hope it helps.